# Trying to make times table calculator in javascript and html

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

I am trying to make a calculator in JavaScript and html so that when a number is entered and calculate is pressed the times table for that number will be displayed however nothing is being outputted. Here is my code any help is greatly appreciated. Many thanks for looking.

```
<html>

<head>
    <title> Javascript</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        var i = 1;
        var result;
        var results = new Array();


        function calculate_this() {
            var input = document.getElementById("input").value;

            do {
                var result = input * i;
                results.push(result);
                i = i + 1;
            }
            while (i < 12);
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = results.string();

        }
    </script>

    <H1>Calculator</H1>
    <input type="text" id="input">
    <input type=button value="Calculate" onClick="calculate_this()">
    <br>
    <H2 id="output"></H2>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you did not initialize i: var i = 0; or better 1: var i = 1;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) method *string()*... There is a method [toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString). So this line:

```
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = results.string();
```

can be updated to this:

```
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = results.toString();
```

```js
var i = 1;
var result;
var results = new Array();


function calculate_this() {
  var input = document.getElementById("input").value;

  do {
    var result = input * i;
    results.push(result);
    i = i + 1;
  }
  while (i < 12);
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = results.toString();

}
```

```html
 <H1>Calculator</H1>
<input type="text" id="input">
<input type=button value="Calculate" onClick="calculate_this()">
<br>
<H2 id="output"></H2>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = results.toString();`

`.string()` is not an array method, so it was throwing an error.